# What is border behavior if borders overlap?(Table-cell,cell-cell)

Tags: java, itext

As Highlighted in the image borders which are getting overlapped look thicker than others cell borders.
Code I have used for applying border on every cell is :

```
cell.setUseVariableBorders(true);
cell.setBorderWidthLeft(1);
cell.setBorderWidthBottom(1);
cell.setBorderWidthRight(1);
cell.setBorderWidthTop(1);
```

[image]

Comment: The border is double width there because 2 cells touch there thusly you have 2 borders touching each-other. Your issue is that they are not overlapping as much as pushing off eachother. If you can establish which cells are touching, you can remove the border for the lower or right of the cells. So Cell 2 is touching Cell1 then do not add a border for Cell 2's left. But Cell 2 is not below any cell so keep the top border.

Comment: They aren't overlapping they are getting placed `adjacent` to other hence showing a thick `border` than others.

Comment: Yeah absolutely @jackjay. Do you any solution for this which works with itext5 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that cause the effect you describe.

1. You are using `cell.setUseVariableBorders(true);` which means that you want the width of the borders to be *inside* the cell. If two adjacent cells have a border next to each other, you will have 2 borders with a width of 1 user unit next to each other, resulting in something that looks as a border with a width of 2 user units.
2. If you remove the line `cell.setUseVariableBorders(true);` the two border will be drawn, but they will overlap. Technically, two overlapping borders of 1 user unit thick should result in something that looks as a single border of 1 user unit thick, but some PDF viewers make overlapping borders slightly thicker than they should be.

How to solve this?

Well, you seem to be new at iText, so why not switch to iText 7? In iText 7, the problem of overlapping borders is solved. All of this is explained in [Chapter 5 of the iText 7 "building blocks" tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2)

If you can't switch to iText 7, but you're stuck with iText 5, you have to remove the line `cell.setUseVariableBorders(true);` and, if that's not sufficient, remove one of the overlapping borders.

Comment: Even after removing the cell.setUseVariableBorders(true); line , it is showing the same behaviour with itext 5.

Comment: That may be caused by the viewer (as I explained). The possible solutions I suggested remain: remove one border of one of the adjacent cells, or upgrade to iText 7

Comment: It is working fine with itext7 but this version is not compatible with itext5.

Comment: Then you have to go for the other option: remove one of the redundant borders.

Comment: I am drawing the border with half width for every adjacent  line and with original width for outer line.Still border does not appear uniform throughout the table.
I am using itext 5 for this can you please help me out.